# Image of $M\boldsymbol{x}$, with $M>0$ and $x_i>0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Recently I came across a problem where the following function appears:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& f: \left(\mathbb{R}^+ \right)^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n \\
& f(\boldsymbol{x}) = M\boldsymbol{x}
\end{split},
\end{equation}
where $M$ is real, symmetric and strictly positive definite (i.e. it is positive definite and full rank).

Is it easy to infer something interesting about the image of $f$?

Initially, I conjectured that the image would be $\left(\mathbb{R}^+\right)^n$, but I found that I was wrong through a counterexample.

Here's everything that I can tell right now:

1. The image is a strict subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$
2. The image is *not* a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$

I think the major difficulties that I find on the analysis of this transformation are a consequence of fact 2...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: All of the eigenvalues of $M$ are positive.

Comment: That is an obvious property of the matrix $M$, not of the transformation itself. I am interested in finding properties of the image of the transformation $f$.

Comment: The eigenvalues should tell you quite a bit about the image.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise in your answer? What do they tell me if I don't even know the eigenvectors? Note also that the entries of the input vector $\boldsymbol{x}$ are all positive.

Comment: Being real symmetric, the matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable. Moreover, its eigenvalues are all positive. $f$ is therefore a combination of dilations in the directions of the eigenvectors. It maps spheres centered at the origin to ellipsoids.

Comment: Ok, that is totally true, but it only takes into account the fact that $M$ is positive definite and invertible and it provides a rather vague result. Let me rephrase my question:

If $\boldsymbol{x}$ may be any real vector, then clearly $Im(f) = \mathbb{R}^n$. What happens if I constrain $\boldsymbol{x}$ to have _positive_ _entries_ _only_?

Comment: Nothing very interesting.